# How to prevent main loading.tsx from showing after any state change in a specific page?

Tags: typescript, next.js

I am having some trouble trying to understand why a part of my code is using the main loading.tsx every single time there is a state change on that specific path.
The path is as follows:

```
app
->loading.tsx
->auth
->auth->email
->auth->email->page
```

In Page.tsx, every time I have a change on any state, the loading.tsx from main shows up for a brief time. I can create a blank loading.tsx in the `auth->email->page` path and use it as a blank loading, however the page blinks every time there is a state change. I don't want loading.tsx to show there at all, no matter the state change.

Is there a way to stop the loading.tsx fallback on specific file paths?